# How do you get the current season using python?

Tags: python

I am looking for the simplest method to ascertain *precisely* the current season (spring, summer, winter, fall) in python.

The first/last day of the season changes each year, so I am unsure where to begin.

I've seen a few astrology libraries that would allow this by finding the position of planets and thus, an equinox. However, this is far too robust.

Comment: How accurate do you need it to be?  For most purposes, using the 21st of the month as the transition is good enough.

Comment: I need it to be precise, so the 21st is not sufficient.

Comment: For what culture or locality? What defines the seasons you're interested in? Meteorological seasons, Astronomical seasons?

Comment: Astronomical I think? Whichever tells me Fall starts on Thursday, September 22

Comment: In which time zone?  See, that's the problem.  The terms are not precise.  If you want to know exactly what time the autumnal equinox occurs in UTC, you can find that out.  https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/books/Syntaxis/Almagest/node36.html

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10901/how-did-meeus-calculate-equinox-and-solstice-dates

Comment: That is unnecessarily precise. If you can find it for UTC, you can find it for any timezone.  That link is not for python.